# how to render only two end points when using GL_LINES in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I'm working on a picking function with OpenGL. I know that I can render 3 lines using `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_Lines);` when the model is a triangle:
[image: 1]

I also know that I can render 3 points using `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_Points);` when the model is a triangle:

[image: 2]

Now I'm running into this problem: I cannot find a way to render 2 endpoints when rendering a line using `GL_LINES`.
Is there anything similar to `glPolygonMode()` that controls how `GL_LINES` works?

Comment: There is nothing such as `glLineMode( )`, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_LINES` describes how the primitive (triangle) is filled in this case.

You can vaguely make out the original primitive even if it is represented as a series of lines or unconnected points rather than a filled triangle. However, for lines, if you simplify them to nothing but points you loose critical information necessary to make any sense of what you are seeing (how those points were connected).

A line mode would make no sense in light of this, and the closest thing that really ever existed would probably be line stippling.

Just use `GL_POINTS` as your primitive instead, you clearly do not require lines for whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything similar to `glPolygonMode()` that controls how `GL_LINES` works?

In one word: No. You'll have to implement this yourself (by simply submitting just the endpoints).

Answer (score 0):

You can render them as [`GL_POINTS` primitives](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Point_Primitive) rather than `GL_LINES`. Of course, you will need to apply a point size for them to be larger more than just a single dot.

Answer (score 0):

As was already pointed out, there is no such thing as a `glLineMode()` call that would allow you to turn lines into points with a simple state setting.

If you can change the draw calls, you can obviously use `GL_POINTS` as the primitive type when you want to draw points.

Contrary to what the other answers claim, I believe there is a way to do this, even if hypothetically you can't modify the draw calls. You could use a geometry shader that has lines as the input primitive type, and points as the output primitive type. The geometry shader could look like this:

```
layout(lines) in;
layout(points, max_vertices = 2) out;

void main() {
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```